# How to correlate Stripe Token with items purchased; prevent spoofing

Tags: javascript, security, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe Checkout for the front-end with the back-end creating the charge with the produced token.

How can I check in the back end that the token created for the purchase of a set of items is indeed for that set of items? Here is a more detailed scenario:

> Item A costs $10
>
> Item B costs $1,000
>
> 1. User chooses B and uses the front-end to generate a Token that was created with an amount of $1,000.
> 2. The front-end sends the token and the purchased item list (just B) to the back-end.
> 3. The back-end can calculate the given purchased item list to calculate a cost (but where can it verify with the token?) of $1,000 for verification that the user bought B and then a charge is made with the token.

My concern is if at step 2 the user spoofs the sent purchase list to be just A (I know that it is worth less than B but this should be rejected still). Then at step 3, how should the back-end figure out to reject making a Stripe Charge with the token?

Attempt:

1. Front-end passes Token, totalCost, listOfItems.
2. Back-end calculates the cost from the listOfItems and checks that it matches the totalCost before creating a Stripe Charge for an amount totalCost.

Is this as secure as it can get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's why you should use webhook
[webhook documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks)

To validate your payment has been made and the amount is correct, you can use webhook instead of user action to trigger. It's common practice nowadays.

After you receive the webhook, you may trigger change of status of the order after your checking (amount, client_info, other checking).